# Collections via MXBeans

Tags: java, collections, jmx

I need to define and implement an MXBean interface. One of the methods would return a Collection. This seems to be not supported by MXBeans. I get an OpenDataException saying "Cannot convert type: java.util.Collection". If I change it to List or Set then it works.

I have not found any documentation saying that Collections are not supported and this is why I am asking you experts. Do I miss something ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The javadoc of the [MXBean](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html) annotation describes in detail the mapping rules. List, Set, SortedSet are supported but not Collection.

Comment: It does describe the mapping rules, but it does not state it would only support those listed types. The `Collection` type would fit into the _Any other type_ category.

Comment: You are right. But I guess that collection is too generic and that the client side does not have enough info (ordered, unique, sorted) to instantiate the good implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Specification does not say it supports Java collections:

> The following list specifies all data types that are allowed as
>   scalars or as anydimensional arrays in open MBeans:
>
> - java.lang.Void
> - java.lang.Short
> - java.lang.Boolean
> - java.lang.Integer
> - java.lang.Byte
> - java.lang.Long
> - java.lang.Character
> - java.lang.Float
> - java.lang.String
> - java.lang.Double
> - java.math.BigDecimal
> - java.math.BigInteger
> - java.util.Date
> - javax.management.ObjectName
> - javax.management.openmbean.CompositeData (interface)
> - javax.management.openmbean.TabularData (interface)

You can use either arrays or TabularData.